# How to remove splash screen and Actionbar in nativescript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm totally new in Nativescript. I'm from the android background and need to know how can I remove splash screen and Actionbar?

Currently, my theme is

```
<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Is there a way to always disable default action bar?

Answer (score 1):

1 - To hide it with a theme:

```
// add to main Activity in mainafest.xml
android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar" 
// or refrence your custom theme
android:theme="@style/#you-theme"
```

2 - To hide it per page:
if you use nativescript core

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" actionBarHidden="true"></Page>
```

if you use angular version

```
import {Page} from "ui/page";
export class AppComponent {
     constructor(privte page: Page) {
          this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set [actionBarVisibility](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/frame#action-bar-visibility) to `never` on your `Frame` to hide the ActionBar Or to hide it on `Page` level set [actionBarHidden](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#showing-or-hiding-the-actionbar) on `Page`

Regarding eliminating the splash image, remove this meta tag from your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />
```

And update theme on your NativeScript Activity from `LaunchScreenTheme` to `AppTheme`

```
<activity android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Tried `actionBarHidden="true"` it worked. Can we disable for the entire project? There is still 2sec white screen on app start.